# How to set internet proxy for amazon s3 server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy

How to set internet proxy for amazon s3.i am getting **Warning: S3::putObject(): [7] Failed connect to Host,No error in E:\wamp\www\S3\s3.php on line 363**.i know this is because of proxy related issue.but i don't know how to add proxy in S3.given below is my code.

index.php

```
<?php
require 's3.php';
$s3 = new S3('ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');
$new_name = time(). '.txt';
S3::putObject(
    $s3->inputFile('upload-me.txt',false),
    'bucket name',
    $new_name,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    array(),
    array(),
    S3::STORAGE_CLASS_RRS   
  );

?>
```

and [s3.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/master/S3.php) which is i downloaded from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/master/S3.php)

thanks in advance:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method [setProxy](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php#L276)

```
S3::setProxy('127.0.0.1:1234');
```

If you are statically calling the [putObject](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php#L625) method, you should set the credentials statically too:

```
S3::setAuth('ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');
```

On the other hand, if you want to do it via AWS SDK directly, refer the "Using a proxy" section on the [client configurations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/configuration.html#client-configuration-options) page.

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'request.options' => array(
        'proxy' => '127.0.0.1:1234'
    )
));

$credentials = new Credentials('ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');
$s3Client->setCredentials($credentials);

$s3Client->putObject(array(
 ...
));
```